# How to get all commune list by district, district by province in database nominatim?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim

I am having a database table of nominatim. Now I want to query all the communes with admin_level = 8, whereby the communes must match the name of its district, city ?

I don't know how to solve it, thank you if you can help me !

Comment: Provide tables structure, sample data and your expectation please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.